# Method to Loop Different/Varying Functions

Tags: c#, function, variables, loops, methods

I'm not sure if the title fits what I am trying to do but I couldn't think of a better way to put it so here goes nothing. I've got an application for modding games that allows you to send mods to multiple different clients at once (you use a checkedListBox). But I don't think it's efficient to have a loop for every different function when multiple clients are selected, so what I am trying to do is have a function that loops through a variable function for each selected client.

```
private void demo()
    {
        foreach (CheckedListBoxItem item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            if (Functions.UFO((uint)item.Value))
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
    }
```

I would have to create a loop like this for every function, which isn't a huge deal but something inside me is screaming "there's a better way!" so I came here.

My initial idea was to use a method with the parameters uint[] clients and Action function. Maybe not even the uint[] (just use the checkedListBox items in the function, but this doesn't work because Actions don't allow for return values. So any help would be appreciated and if I can make this question any clearer please let me know, it's late and I'm tired so I definitely could have missed something!

Comment: Func<> returns value while Action<> doesn't; e.g. Func<Boolean, int> takes int and returns Boolean

Comment: What's wrong with above code? Using a construct with Func<> would only make it harder to understand, but in no way better.

Comment: @ThomasWeller the issue is that while the above code is fine for one function, I've got about 36 that support this "multi-client" functionality, so doing the loop in each one seems very repetitive.